# What's the best practice for requests.session sharing between requests in a Django Rest Framework web application?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, python-requests

Is it safe to use a global, static session to communicate with external APIs?  Is there a reasonable indicator for when a session should be refreshed, or is using a session a bad idea?

Background: I'm currently working through optimizing a Django Rest Framework application that is taking too long (>1.2 seconds) to get responses from a remote API.  Based on their timings, and comparing it to a few run-throughs on Postman, the longest running components seem to be a combination of TCP and SSL handshake when they weren't cached (running django_cprofile_middleware against the endpoint showed a similar theme, with hundreds of milliseconds being spent on those aforementioned handshakes).  I was able to get those interactions down to about the same in the application as in Postman after the first request by using a shared requests.session instead of a basic requests.get (closer to 200 ms per request).